# Lost in the ice - Who am I?

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge

I am hotter than the sun and keep out of sight.
I guide you on your way when you travel at night.
I measure the ozone at a great height.

Yet I was lost in the ice.

What am I?

Answer (score 19):

Maybe it is:

> Polaris

I am hotter than the sun and keep out of sight

> the north star's temperature is higher than the sun's and we can't see it at daylight or in the southern hemisphere.

I guide you on your way when you travel at night.

> [Polaris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polaris), the north star, which is very close to the north celestial pole and so guides travellers to the north at night.

I measure the ozone at a great height

> The Photochemistry of Ozone Loss in the Arctic Region In Summer ([POLARIS](https://espo.nasa.gov/home/polaris/content/POLARIS)) is the latest in a series of high-altitude airborne investigations of atmospheric ozone.

Yet I was lost in the ice (credit to @Morgan G)

> refers to the  [Polaris expedition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polaris_expedition) (1871)

Comment: You got one line right! But I'm looking for another name for this thing.

Comment: Closest answer so far!

Comment: Right answer! But only 2 out of 4 clues solved.

Comment: For the last clue: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polaris_expedition

Comment: @Morgan G - yes. 1 to go... Not sure how to credit you with it though as I can only accept one answer.

Comment: No need for credit, just helping to find the correct answer

Comment: Nobody has yet solved the first clue...

Comment: @DavidGlickman Is the first clue a reference to the fact Polaris is a dual star system; maybe a hotter, smaller star hidden by the larger one? This could be wrong; I just vaguely remember reading something along these lines at some point when I used to do astronomy...

Comment: No. It's another thing called Polaris.

Answer (score 11):

The answer is

> Helium

I am hotter than the sun and keep out of sight.

> There are stars that are hotter than the sun, they are made of burning helium. Helium is also usually invisible to the human eye.

I guide you on your way when you travel at night.

> Stars are used for navigation at night

I measure the ozone at a great height.

> Scientists use helium-filled [weather balloons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weather_balloon) to measure ozone levels in the atmosphere.

Yet I was lost in the ice.

> Helium is soluble in ice, which makes measuring helium levels using ice cores difficult.

Answer (score 8):

You are

> the earth’s core.

I am hotter than the sun and keep out of sight.

> The Earth’s core is [hotter than the surface of the sun](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-Earths-core-hotter-than-Suns-surface). It can’t be seen by us surface dwellers.

I guide you on your way when you travel at night.

> The earth’s core consists mainly of molten iron which generates a magnetic field as the earth spins. This magnetic field causes other magnets such as the needle of a compass to align with it and point to the magnetic north pole, allowing travellers to navigate when they have no other way of telling which direction is north.

I measure the ozone at a great height.

> The magnetic field extends far further than the surface of the earth and [influences the amount of ozone in the upper atmosphere](http://www.theozonehole.com/magnetic.htm).

Yet I was lost in the ice.

> During the ice ages, much of the earth’s surface was covered in ice.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Some interesting facts there I didn't know, good explanations and some nice research, +1!

Comment: Measuring the ozone means measuring not influencing.

Comment: Thanks @BeastlyGerbil I've recently enjoyed some of the puzzles that show up in Hot Network Questions and this time, I thought I'd take a look for one that hadn't been answered.

Answer (score 5):

It could be

> Solar Radiation (Or one of the other names for it)

I am hotter than the sun and keep out of sight.

> The sun's rays are [5778 Kelvin](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/9983/temperature-of-the-suns-rays) and the Sun is 5777 Kelvin [according to Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?espv=2&rlz=1C1CHZL_enGB686GB686&q=how%20hot%20is%20the%20sun&oq=how%20hot%20is%20the%20sun&gs_l=serp.3..35i39k1j0i67k1j0l8.463.463.0.752.1.1.0.0.0.0.76.76.1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..0.1.74.Xc4S932bT1M). You can't see the sun's rays either because they are Ultra-Violet (UV)

I guide you on your way when you travel at night.

> The rays reflect off the moon which is why it looks like it glows. The moonlight could light our way at night

I measure the ozone at a great height.

> The ozone layer keeps most UV Rays out

Yet I was lost in the ice

> Ice absorbs these rays